# google cloud reinstalled nginx by mistake how i can revert it back

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, google-cloud-platform, nginx-config

there was a wordpress site on the server when i open the site i got this message 
Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

Comment: Did you try snapshot?

Comment: It always a best practice to take the [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of the VM to avoid such situations. That's being said, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852224/restore-current-sites-available-file) discussion thread, where they have explained some steps to restore current config which exist in the memory. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that your instance's IP address changed. It is very unlikely that Google will replace anything inside your instance. you were likely browsing to your public IP address directly and stumbled upon another customer's website (Your formal [Ephemeral IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#externaladdresses) address being now assigned to them). To avoid this you need to set a [Static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#externaladdresses).

As noted in the comments above, the only way to revert a Compute Engine instance to a previous status is to restore an existing [Persistent Disk Snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots).